# Was there an update to Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am relatively new to Flutter and so, I am using videos on YouTube to aid my journey. I try to use more recent tutorials but the one that I am very far in was made in 2020. So the firebase documentation changed and I am not sure what to do. **I commented the errors that I am getting.**

```
 if (user != null) 
{
 // Undefined Class UserUpdateInfo
 // The method 'UserUpdateInfo' isn't defined for the type '_RegisterViewState'
 //Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.       
 UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
 updateUser.displayName = _usernameController.text;
 user.updateProfile(updateUser);
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`updateProfile` is deprecated and is replaced by `updatePhotoURL` and `updateDisplayName`.

In your case you're trying to update the username then you can use `updateDisplayName` like this.

```
if (user != null){
   user.updateDisplayName(_usernameController.text);
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.menu);
}
```